# Not able to upload the product images

Tags: magento-1.8

[image]

Hi Guys , I changed the  media folder permission 777 ,
drwxrwxrwx  4 geetha geetha   4096 Jun 25 15:16 media.
I updated browser not help.
I installed Flash player not help.
I flushed the magento cash not help.
In the System.log  not showing any error.
One more thing i have to mention is that , we have three systems running Uubuntu 12.04 , its happening in only one system. in other two we dont have any problem.
please tell me What could be the problem?

Comment: I can't comment so I'll just put my comment here in the answer box. Sorry to ask but what was the message after you uploaded the image? Can you please also paste it here? I probably can help you out.

Comment: There was no error message , thats yellow strip with image information . nothing else.

Comment: You probably uploaded a huge image file. Check the memory_limit in your php.ini. Set it to something like 512M. If that doesn't work, install php5 gd library.

Answer (score 0):

Your upload went successfully but you need to go to system > Configuration > Web and set the correct media path. Looks like its behind https